# Passing user parameters to SSIS package

Tags: c#, ssis

Here's my problem. I have a SSIS package that takes 1 parameter on input called SegmentID. But I cant pass it from the c# code. I'm searching for2 days so far, and here's a solution I came up with, which should work, but doesn't - SSIS package fails at the stage of getting parameter. What a hell am I doing wrong?

```
        using (SqlConnection con = GetConnection())
        {
            var integrationServices = new IntegrationServices(con);

            if (integrationServices.Catalogs.Contains("SSISDB"))
            {
                var catalog = integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"];

                if (catalog.Folders.Contains("PSO"))
                {
                    var folder = catalog.Folders["PSO"];

                    if (folder.Projects.Contains("PSO_SSIS"))
                    {
                        var project = folder.Projects["PSO_SSIS"];

                        project.Parameters["SegmentID"].Set(ParameterInfo.ParameterValueType.Literal, segmentID);

                        if (project.Packages.Contains("Main.dtsx"))
                        {
                            var package = project.Packages["Main.dtsx"];

                            long executionIdentifier = package.Execute(false, null);
                            return catalog.Executions[executionIdentifier];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There a few different ways of working with Parameters in the 2012 project model. Are you trying to configure the Project's parameter to be the segmentId or a specific instance of execution's segmentID?

Comment: Not sure (it's been a while I don't play with SSIS), I think you give the parameter to the project, not to the package. So, `project.Parameters`... should be `package.Parameters`, no?

Comment: Well, actually the package is written by another person, I'm just supposed to launch it. I tried to pass this parameter to package A LOT, but failed. In debug mode I saw, that this parameter is actually beloning to Project, not package (for some reason). The package itself starts with a task which looks like as follows: select * from <some table name> where SegmentID= ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks, guys, but i figured it out. You have to do something like this:

```
var setValueParameters = new Collection<PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet>();
                            setValueParameters.Add(new PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet
                            {
                                ObjectType = 20,
                                ParameterName = "SegmentID",
                                ParameterValue = 1
                            });
```

and then call:

```
long executionIdentifier = package.Execute(false, null, setValueParameters);
```

Why it confused me so much is that I thought that this thing is just for system parameters, like logging level or something, and NOWHERE was mentioned that the code for user parameters is 20, and this construction can be used for assigning them. Hope it'll help somebody to avoid butthurt I had for 2 days.